# Merging 2 Transparent Images Into a Picturebox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, gdi+, transparency

I am trying to use GDI+ to merge two PNG's with transparency that I have stored in an ImageList, and then show this in a PictureBox. My PictureBox size, first image size, and second image size are all the same. I thought this would be simple but the following code does not work and I am not sure why. I have searched but I could not find any code snippets specifically dealing with PictureBoxes.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
    Dim myGraphic As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics
    myGraphic.DrawImageUnscaled(ImageList1.Images(0), 0, 0)
    myGraphic.DrawImageUnscaled(ImageList1.Images(1), 0, 0)        
End Sub
```

Does anyone know what I am missing? At the moment when I click the button I see the PictureBox flicker with the image for a splitsecond.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh now I understand what I've done wrong.

Here is my revised code. Problem solved.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim newimage As New Bitmap(ImageList1.Images(0).Width, ImageList1.Images(0).Height)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newimage)
        g.DrawImage(ImageList1.Images(0), 0, 0)
        g.DrawImage(ImageList1.Images(1), 0, 0)
        PictureBox1.Image = newimage
        g.Dispose()    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're drawing the images in the exact same location so you do risk that one image is completely overwriting the other.

That said, it's not enough just to draw on the graphic. You need to invalidate the picture box control too. This will force it to redraw itself.

As a crude test with your current program, you can minimize it and then maximize it and see if the PNGs are there. This will also force-redraw the picturebox.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
It's supposed to overwrite it because the second image is an overlay with transparency. An example of what I am trying to achieve can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Merge_Images_in_C_.aspx I want to do that but instead of writing to a file I want to show it in a PictureBox (and my program is in VB.Net not C#).
Could you please explain what you mean by invalidate the picturebox?
And I tried the minimize/maximize thing but nothing happened.

Comment: Easy: Just call the Control.Invalidate() method. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate(v=vs.71).aspx It exists because drawing to the actual screen is a costly process. So instead of showing each step of each thing you draw on a drawable surface, you draw all of it and tell the surface to update itself. That said, *I think you're going down the wrong path alltogether* with your approach. You should place all drawing logic in the control's **Paint-event**.